# How can I permanently set a Network Bridge to Private in Windows 11?

Tags: networking, windows-11, ethernet, home-networking, network-adapter

I have a Network Bridge connecting two PCs, configured as follows:

1. PC 1 is connected to my local network via Ethernet
2. PC 2 is connected directly to PC 1 via Ethernet

A Network Bridge is setup and configured to bridge the connections of PC 1 and PC 2.

PC 1 requires Internet access. PC 2 only requires Local Network access. Both PCs are assigned a static IP address, with PC 1 having the static IP address 192.168.1.4, and PC 2 having the static IP address 192.168.1.5.

When I power on the PCs, the Network Bridge is always an `Unidentified network`, and always defaults to `Public`. This prevents PC 1 and PC 2 from being able to see and communicate with each other. Manually changing the Network Category to `Private` via `Set-NetConnectionProfile` solves this problem, until the next time the PCs boot up and/or reboot. I've tried updating my Local Security Policy to always set Unidentified networks to `Private` by default, but this has no effect on my Network Bridge.

Is there a way to change my Network Bridge to not be an Unidentified network? How can I implement a permanent solution so that the Network Bridge is always `Private`?

[Get-NetConnectionProfile Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfbuJ.png)

[ipconfig all (Public)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFZrA.png)

[Ethernet Settings - PC 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHRk2.png)

[Ethernet Settings - PC 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zxHg.png)

[Hardware and connection properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hvho.png)

[Network Bridge Additional Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXOef.png)

[Local Security Policy - Unidentified Networks setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoLsj.png)

[ipconfig all (Private)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zN9UP.png)

Comment: I have a similar problem with a bridge enabling a HyperV VM to be reached/reach the external network. (The "New Virtual Switch that is bridged" option in HyperV manager.)

Answer (score 1):

I am glad to help with such technological difficulties.
There are a few possible ways to change your network bridge to private and make it permanent. Here are some of my steps:
You can use the Registry Editor to modify the Category value of your network profile from 0 (Public) to 1 (Private) 1. You will have to run the Registry Editor as admin and go to the following directory as displayed: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles. Next, locate the ProfileName of your network bridge and open it by double-clicking on the Category DWORD to change its value. You will have to reboot your PC1 to ensure the changes to take effect.
If for some reason this fails to work, then use the WinPowerShell by doing the following displayed below:
effect.
use the PowerShell to change the network category of your network bridge to private 2. To do this, run the WinPowerShell as admin and type the following commands down:

### You will need to change NetWorkConnection Category to Private

##Remember to run these commands as admin

Get-NetConnectionProfile |
Where { $*.NetWorkCategory -ne 'Private'} |
ForEach {
$*
$_|Set-NetConnectionProfile -NetWorkCategory Private -Confirm
}

If this fails to work then you must consult a technical you trust to fix this repeating issue.

Comment: I'm able to change my connection category to Private, as I pointed out in my post. That's not the problem. The problem is that it does not persist, and resets to Public every time I reboot.